# Hiding a image when start editing textview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextview

I have an image overlapping on the UITextView. I would like to hide the image when user started touching the text view and start editing. What code should i use? 
I tried the following code but does not work.

```
-(IBAction)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    img1.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the UITextView properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
 img1.hidden=YES;
}
```

Also, don't forget to implement the following so you can unhide it when the textView stops editing.

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
  img1.hidden=NO;
}
```

You also have to make sure your delegate is setup properly like:

```
myTextViewName.delegate = self; //This should probably go in the viewDidLoad section.

<UITextViewDelegate> //This should go after the @interface ViewController : UIViewController (or similar) in your headers file (.h). So it should look something like @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
     img1.hidden=YES;

}
```

This will hide the image view

and

```
 - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
       img1.hidden=NO;
}
```

This will show image when editing done.